# no pg_hba.conf for entry postgres remote connection error when catch all mask in pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql

Getting the following error while trying to connect to postgres remotely...

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "109.153.58.128", user "colemans", database "colemanbros", SSL off
```

But the `pg_hba.conf` I have contains the following

```
host    colemans        colemanbros     0.0.0.0/0       md5
host    colemans        colemans        0.0.0.0/0       md5
```

Both are valid users and the database is correct. Why is it failing?

The IP mask of 0.0.0.0/0 should catch all incoming connections, right?

Or am I doing something wrong?

PS: the `postgresql.conf` file is set to listen on '*'

Answer (score 1):

According to [the official Postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) the order of your entries is wrong. It should be like:

```
host    database        user            address         auth-method  [auth-options]
```

In your case(based on your error):

```
host    colemanbros     colemans        0.0.0.0/0       md5
```

Comment: That's what I've got ?   HOST / DB / USER  / ADDRESS / AUTH

Comment: I've set up the pg_hba file before for specific address' before but its not working for a catch all.

Comment: Then you are using wrong connection string.

Comment: Thanks for this, you were correct, as much as I didn't believe you. Connection string was incorrect.

Comment: On BBC' s Sherlock tv series they describes [Occam' s razer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) which is your situation :). I always try to give a shoot to counter opinion.